# Use JavaScript to change BigCommerce category price if $0.00

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I was able to switch out the price for text if the text was $0.00 on a product page with the footer script I found here:

http://forum.bigcommerce.com/f4/changing-text-with-javascript-10745/?highlight=javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ProductPriceRating em:contains("$0.00")').text("Price Updates w/ Option Selction");
$('.ProductPrice:contains("$0.00")').text("Price Updates w/ Option Selction");
</script>
```

The problem is it doesn't work for the category page price whose class is ".ProductPriceCat em".

The site is already using an old version of JQuery, so I am trying to avoid it if I can. I am hoping for a JavaScript solution.

Can someone help me, please?

Update - This does not work either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ProductPriceCat.em:contains("$0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a misunderstanding the *class* attribute;

```
<span class="foo bar"></span>
```

means that the `<span>` has two classes, `foo` and `bar`. **The *class* attribute is a space-seperated list of values.** Therefore, the CSS selectors `.foo` and `.bar` both will find this *Element*.

However, if you put them together with a space, the selector `.foo bar` actually means

> Find all `<bar>`s that looks like `<tag class="foo"><bar></bar></tag>`

If you want to join them, the correct selector is `.foo.bar` which means

> Find all nodes which have class `foo` and class `bar`

Comment: I tried this but it did not work:

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.ProductPriceCat.em:contains("$0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

First: Many Bigcommerce stores use the ProductPrice class on category pages as well.

If your category template conforms to this, then use:

```
$('.ProductPrice em:contains("$0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
```

If your category template uses the class ProductPriceCat, then use:

```
$('.ProductPriceCat em:contains("$0.00")').text("Call For A Quote!");
```

The reason your code does not work is that you have a syntax error. There should be a space between .ProductPriceCat and em - not a period.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try that as well, but I had no success with that method.

Comment: Where are you adding the code? I successfully ran this locally via the console.